# My WCF service started to close connection after a 2 years of good work

Tags: c#, wcf

There is a strange problem with me good working WCF service. Suddenly it starts to close connection too fast. I did no changes nor to the service nor to the client. I suspect that the machine where service is running is working slower but this also started to happen on my machine too.
To overcome this problem I changed my app.config file to have the following configuration:

```
    <services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="eit" name="Siv.WcfTcpProxy.WcfTcpDataProxyService">
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:51646/WcfTcpProxy" binding="netTcpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" name="default" contract="Siv.WcfTcpProxy.IWcfTcpDataProxy" />
    <host>
      <timeouts closeTimeout="00:01:10" />
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

    <binding name="NewBinding0" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
      sendTimeout="00:10:00" transactionFlow="true" transferMode="Buffered"
      maxBufferSize="655360" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="655360" maxStringContentLength="655360"
        maxArrayLength="655360" maxBytesPerRead="655360" maxNameTableCharCount="655360" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

But this is still not helps.
My contract is the following:

```
// a service contract.
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Siv.WcfTcpProxy", 
    CallbackContract = typeof(IDataCallback), 
    SessionMode = SessionMode.Required,
    ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None)]
public interface IWcfTcpDataProxy
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool PassData(byte[] data, int clientId);

    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = true)]
    SubscriptionData Subscribe(string appVersion, string appName);

    [OperationContract(IsTerminating = true)]
    void Unsubscribe(int id);
}

// a service contract callback.
public interface IDataCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ResendData(byte[] data);
}

// Service class which implements the service contract.
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true,
    UseSynchronizationContext = false,
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
//[ErrorBehavior(typeof(CalculatorErrorHandler))]
public class WcfTcpDataProxyService : ServiceBase, IWcfTcpDataProxy
{
...
}
```

What I see in the WCF trace is that connection closed after sending a response to Subscribe(). But still I may misinterpret the WCF logs.

Any clues are welcome, including good reading material about advanced WCF.

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but you can check that the system clocks on the client and server are in sync. WCF can throw security exceptions when they are more than e.g., 10 minutes apart.

Comment: I do not see any exceptions in the WCF trace.

Comment: Also check any firewall rules. I have seen poorly coded firewall rules causing connections to be closed when they shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a few environmental causes:

Check the system clocks, as ShellShock pointed out. The sku value is generally 5 minutes. WCF trace might give you nothing, you might need to check event viewer in both server side and client side.

Firewall rules as ShellShock pointed out. Have you or system admin had make some changed the rules, with might terminate/corrupted some "suspicious" connections? you need to consult with the system admin and inspect the verbose details of the http conversations.

Windows updates. Have your Windows updated in recent days when the problem occurred? I had experience that certain update of .NET had introduced problems.

To isolated possible environmental factors, you have better to have a few testing environments and be conservative in system updates/upgrades. For example, you should turn the Windows auto update off and get notified. When do some machine settings changes, such as machine.config or firewall rules, do it in the test or the staging environments first, and observe and test for a few days.